# C# how to get the name (in string) of a class property?

Tags: c#

```
public class TimeZone
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName{ get; set; }
}
```

In some other class I've:

```
   var gmtList = new SelectList(
       repository.GetSystemTimeZones(), 
       "Id",
       "DisplayName");
```

*Note: System.Web.Mvc.SelectList*

I do not like to have to write the property name with "Id" and "DisplayName". Later in time, maybe the property name will change and the compiler will not detect this error.
C# how to get property name in a string?

**UPDATE 1**

With the help of Christian Hayter, 
I can use:

```
var tz = new TimeZone();
var gmtList = new SelectList(
    repository.GetSystemTimeZones(), 
    NameOf(() => tz.Id), 
    NameOf(() => tz.TranslatedName));
```

OR

```
var gmtList = new SelectList(
    repository.GetSystemTimeZones(), 
    NameOf(() => new TimeZone().Id), 
    NameOf(() => new TimeZone().TranslatedName));
```

If someone has other idea without the need of creating a new object. Feel free to share it :) thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could create a utility method to extract the property name from an expression tree, like this:

```
string NameOf<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expr) {
    return ((MemberExpression) expr.Body).Member.Name;
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
var gmtList = new SelectList(repository.GetSystemTimeZones(),
    NameOf(() => tz.Id),
    NameOf(() => tz.DisplayName));
```

Note that any instance of the class will do, since you are not reading the property value, only the name.

Comment: This is a great solution, but keep in mind any performance overhead from using expression trees as well as the amount of refactoring necessary when it comes time to change all the references. It may even be negligible, but there's only one way to find out!

Comment: I haven't profiled this, but theoretically the code is working from an expression tree object graph that has already been constructed by the compiler, so it should be quite fast to read the name. If you want to read the *value* of the expression, that's quite a different matter!

Comment: Any performance testing done on this? Would it be wise to use it with MVVM INotifyPropertyChanged?

Answer (score 0):

(Those aren't parameters btw, they're properties.)

Well, one option is to use delegates. For example:

```
public class SelectList<T>
{
    public SelectList(IEnumerable<T> source,
                      Func<T, string> idProjection,
                      Func<T, string> displayProjection)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then:

```
var gmtList = new SelectList<TimeZone>(repository.GetSystemTimeZones(),
                                       tz => tz.Id, tz => tz.DisplayName);
```

Comment: Nice option but the 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' cannot be used with type arguments. So, I can't use this solution. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @asdas: If you'd said which type it was to start with, that would have helped a great deal. You gave us no context whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

`var name = (string) typeof(TimeZone).GetProperty("DisplayName").GetValue(0);`

Comment: Once again you are writing the DisplayName withing Quotation marks. Not what I am looking for :) Thanks anyway.

Comment: You can replace it with a variable that gets its value from an external data source, silly : )

Answer (score 0):

```
string id=typeof(TimeZone).GetProperties()[0].Name;
string displayName=typeof(TimeZone).GetProperties()[1].Name;


var gmtList = new SelectList(
   repository.GetSystemTimeZones(), 
   id,
   displayName);
```

this will work, unless the order in which id and displayname  declared doesn't change.
 or else you can think of defining an attribute for the property to differentiate between id and displayname.

Comment: Is a working solution :) but not very practical and bullet proof. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since C# 6.0, you can now use

```
var gmtList = new SelectList(
    repository.GetSystemTimeZones(), 
    nameof(TimeZone.Id),
    nameof(TimeZone.DisplayName));
```